# How to add extra addons products value to Subtotal value in Woocommerce Cart using PPOM plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, add-on

I have some **extra product values** i.e. pizza extras toppings - lettuce, chicken etc in my woo-commerce site. So, that will be added with that pizza and all value should get added to the main subtotal. But the main problem is, when I increase the quantity of the Pizza, the quantity of extra product values are not increasing, they are always 1. I have tried to solve that problem in **jquery** by calling **extra-addons-price class**, however, I don't know how I can do the same in PHP code. As right now I know only this function

```
$cart_total = WC()->cart->get_subtotal() //it returns 10.99 and 4.99 shown on uploaded photo
```

but, I want to know how I can know the extra item prices like salami = 1.60.

[image]

you can see that on the image, the calculation is wrong. The subtotal should be 25.18 and 10.98 respectively. I am using **PPOM for WooCommerce  By Themeisle** . By default, this plugin doesn't work in case of a product increase. However, I want to tweak it as I have already achieved it using **Jquery** but I need to know the parameter to fetch the **extra value prices**.

The below code works fine and solved my problem, but I want to convert it to PHP code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents', 'calculate_ppom_total_price', 10, 2 );
function updateSubtotal() {
            jQuery('.woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item').each(function() {
                var subtotal = 0;
                var priceString = jQuery(this).find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text();
                var price = parseFloat(priceString.replace('$', ''));
                var quantity = jQuery(this).find('.input-text.qty').val();

                jQuery(this).find('.ppom-option-label-price').each(function() {
                    var additionalPriceString = jQuery(this).text();
                    var additionalPrice = parseFloat(additionalPriceString.replace('[+$', '').replace(']', ''));
     
                    price += additionalPrice;
                });

                subtotal += price;
                var totalWithQty = subtotal * quantity;
                jQuery(this).find('.product-subtotal .woocommerce-Price-amount').html('<bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>' + totalWithQty.toFixed(2) + '</bdi>');
            });
            
        }
```

Comment: Uve got it wrong the option is added in the total of your product so the total is 10.99 incl the option. Here is from their demo - https://prnt.sc/B1ggCW9sP2lJ so if you change the qty to 2 will be $6 for this product.

Comment: The demo you have given its only for single product page this doesn't work in cart page. what i want is, if one pizza cost is 10.99 with toppings 1.60 then total is 12.59, but if I increase the pizza qty to 2, then it should muliply whole 12.59*2 =25.18.

Comment: Lets say your pizza cost $1 and topings are $2 total for this pizza is $3 so 2 pizzas are $6 etc - https://prnt.sc/r2GvZutzMuhY i dont see a problem in the plugin demo. And on your screenshot your total cost of the product is 10,99. If you want to show price of product itself then you must calc 10,99 - 1.6 and that will be your base price.

Comment: If you speak of having double toping then its a different case and this plugin doesnt do that. Here qty is for the whole product not for topings or w/e.

Comment: yes i want to double topping if product gets double, I know this plugin doesn't do that. that's why I want to customize that, I have already done that with jquery, but with PHP I am struggling to fetch the meta-data for extra product. that;s why I posted this question

Comment: If author dont have documentation ask if they have a hook that you can use otherwise you will need to hook into woocommerce_before_calculate_totals so you can modify your product price. There are many examples here and internet about this hook that u can use for base. If you still have problems with it share your product object from the cart so we can have more info about the structure.